# self-signed certificate issue in IIS 7.0

Tags: iis, iis-7, windows-vista, https, certificate

I am setting up IIS 7.0 on a Windows Vista box. I am using self-signed certificate (by using built-in Create Self-Signed Certificate feature of IIS 7.0) on a web site. The I can browse from the local machine (the machine with IIS and web site) for the https address, for example, https://machinename/test.html, it works.

But when I browse another machine, using the same url, https://machinename/test.html, it does not work (browsers shows cannot connect error message). when browse from another machine using http, e.g. http://machinename/test.html, it works. Any ideas what is wrong? Any limitation of self-signed certificate from another machine?

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Verify that SSL port 443 is allowed by the system's firewall.

Comment: I have a related question here, appreciate if you could take a look. Thanks!